# Error when attempting to run JUnit test runner

Tags: java, command-line, junit

I am attempting to use JUnit for the first time, but I seem to be having some issues when running my compiled test runner. I am using java from the command-line and running macOS.

I successfully compiled my two jar files and 4 java source files using the following command:

> javac -classpath junit-4.12.jar:jar2.jar StackLinkedTestRunner.java 2.java 3.java 4.java

However, when I execute `java StackLinkedTestRunner`, I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/junit/runner/JUnitCore    at
>   StackLinkedTestRunner.main(StackLinkedTestRunner.java:9) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 1 more

I've googled the error, but I really don't understand any of the returned problems or solutions. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain what I'm doing incorrectly and how I can go about fixing it.

Comment: This is super-basic stuff. Don't confuse yourself with JUnit ... when you don't understand how you make javac and java work nicely together regarding that classpath aspect. In essence: when your .java source has dependencies on other JARs to allow compiling, then you need those JARs in your classpath also when running your class using Java. As said: super basic stuff; documented a zillion times out there.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the classpath for the java compiler but you have to set the classpath for the java execution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would I just execute `java -classpath junit-4.12.jar:jar2.jar StackLinkedTestRunner.java 2.java 3.java 4.java` ?

Comment: I'm not real experienced running it from the command line but I believe it would be `java -classpath junit-4.12.jar:jar2.jar StackLinkedTestRunner`

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class StackLinkedTestRunner".